# Nginx Nodejs Rest API Endpoints returning 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I am trying to setup a local server for local network use. The React app works fine and can be access from another computer on the network. The problem is, the API endpoints I created is returning 404 error (but not the Nginx 404). It's being treated like a regular Reactjs app internal page.

Here is my Nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/build;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    # This is the react app
    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # This is the restful api
    location /api {
            proxy_redirect       off;
            default_type         application/json;
            proxy_pass_header    Server;
            proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header     X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header     Content-Type: application/json;
            proxy_set_header     Host $host;
            proxy_set_header     X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_connect_timeout   5;
            proxy_read_timeout      240;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;
            proxy_pass           http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

Here's my React app `package.json:

```
{
    "name": "React APP",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "scripts": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": { 
        ...
    },
    "homepage": "."
}
```

From my localhost machine, I am able to visit `http://localhost/` and it shows me my ReactApp just fine, however, `http://localhost/api/v1/` and all its endpoints aren't mapping correctly. But if I visit `http://localhost:5000`, I am able to access my api just fine too.

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The applications run on different ports, 80 for React Application and 5000 for NodeJS server. Have two separate configurations for the two applications under the conf.d folder  i.e. react.conf below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/build;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    # This is the react app
    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

and for the NodeJS endpoint you can have i.e nodejs.conf

```
server {
            listen  80 default_server;
            server_name   nodeapi.com;
            # Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS
            location / {
                        proxy_redirect       off;
                        default_type         application/json;
                        proxy_pass_header    Server;
                        proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_a dd_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header     X-Scheme $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header     Content-Type: application/json;
                        proxy_set_header     Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header     X-NginX-Proxy true;
                        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
                        proxy_read_timeout      240;
                        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
                        proxy_pass         "http://localhost:5000";
               }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ignatius, I tried your solution and I do see progress, but its now resulting to 405 Nginx Not Allowed. Any ideas?

Comment: 405 indicates the method you are calling the endpoint is not allowed. The API you have defined does it expect a POST or GET request types?

Comment: I can send POST and GET requests directly from `http://localhost:5000` and responds just fine. But not sure why `http://192.168.100.9/api` or `http://localhost/api` returns 405.
Btw, I forgot to mention I modified your nodejs conf location from `/` to location `/api`. And also, the server is `http://192.168.100.9` on the network, and the one that's trying to access it is `http://192.168.100.10`

Comment: but even if I access the server directly from the `192.168.100.9` pc, only `http://localhost:5000` works via postman.

Comment: Share you configuration for both applications.